# Laravel multiauth md5 and primary key string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

currently i have 1 project need to use extend mysql database which has a lot of data and password is md5 encrypted and the MEMBER_ID(primary key) is string like this

> 5e3bb0bdb70e4f139c132cc32daace0e

the password field name **PASSWORD** and the primary key name **MEMBER_ID**

so i set the eloquent model like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

class Member extends BaseModels implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

    protected $connection = 'mysql_db2';

    protected $table = 'tb_member';

    protected $primaryKey = 'MEMBER_ID';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $hidden = ['PASSWORD'];

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->MEMBER_ID;
    }

    public function setPASSWORDAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['PASSWORD'] = static::encryptPassword($value);
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {dd('set');
        $this->PASSWORD = static::encryptPassword($password);
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {dd('get');
        return $this->PASSWORD;
    }

    public static function encryptPassword($password) {
        return md5($password);
    }

    public function checkLogin($username, $password) {
        if ($this->USERNAME == $username && $this->PASSWORD == static::encryptPassword($password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i search around and found some post mention to add the **getAuthPassword()** and **setPassword()** method, but i die dump there it also pass, so i think is deprecated in laravel 5.2?

and here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\Member;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class MemberController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    public function login(Request $request) {
        $username = $request->get('username');
        $password = $request->get('password');

        try {
            $member = Member::where('USERNAME', '=', $username)->first();
            dd(Auth::guard('member')->attempt([
                'USERNAME' => $username,
                'PASSWORD' => $password
            ]));
            if ($member) {
                if ($member->checkLogin($username, $password)) {

                    Auth::guard('member')->login($member);
                    if (Auth::guard('member')->check()) {
//                        dd(Auth::guard('member')->check());
                        return redirect()->route('frontend.index');
                    } else {
                        return redirect()->route('frontend.index')->withErrors();
                    }
                } else {
                    return 'Incorrect password';
                }
            } else {
                return 'Username not found';
            }
            $d = new Member();
            $d->PASSWORD = 123456;

            $credentials = [
                'USERNAME' => $username,
                'PASSWORD' => $password
            ];
            if (Auth::guard('member')->attempt($credentials)) {
                return 'successfully login';
            } else {
                return 'unable to login';
            }
            return 'hehe';
//            dd($username, $password);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd('FILE: ' . $e->getfile() . 'LINE: ' . $e->getLine() . '<br />' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

the **Auth::guard('member')->attempt() always return false**

the **Auth::guard('member')->login($member) always return null**

**Auth::guard('member')->check()** return true when the page not refresh, but once refresh(or go another route/page) the **Auth::guard('member')->check()** will then return false

i cannot change the password encrypt method, i cannot add a auto increment field or edit the primary key to the member table because another website maintainer say it might cause his JAVA application error, so any idea without changing any table structure?

UPDATE:

i found some article http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5

i did the custom auth and finally **Auth::guard('member')->attempt return true**

but once the page refresh or go another page/route, the **Auth::guard('member')->check() return false again**

UPDATE 2:

i try dump **dd(\Session::all())** at index and i found the session get cleared, but when i try dump **dd(\Session::all())** after **Auth::guard('member')->attempt**, the session show

```
array:1 [▼
  "login_member_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => "5e3bb0bdb70e4f139c132cc32daace0e"
]
```

why is the session get cleared?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, is because session not started

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/auth-session-killed-after-redirect-laravel-52

app/Http/routes.php

```
//Frontend route
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Frontend', 'middleware' => ['web']), function() {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'frontend.index', 'uses' => 'IndexController@index']);
});
```

app/Http/kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'member' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'web' => \App\Http\Middleware\Web::class,
    ];
}
```

app/Http/Middleware/Web.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Web
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```